# Windows 8 virtualization enabled in BIOS but doesn't seem to be working. Also no hyper-v installed

Tags: windows-8, virtual-machine, bios, virtualization

I am trying to use Android Studio on my machine. After attempting to run emulators, I was getting errors letting me know that my virtualization was disabled. Therefore, I went to BIOS and enabled it with vt-x only toggle.

However, my machine still says that virtualization is disabled. I have been trying to resolve the problem on my own and i found it's good to disable Hyper-v which I don't appear to have on my Windows 8.1 windows features on and off toggling despite my task manager that there is Hyper-V supporting my machine (unless I don't understand something). I don't know what to do. Begging for some answers!

My machine is Toshiba Satellite CS5
Windows 8.1 not pro version

[Task Manager screenshot - virtualisation disabled but Hyper-V support enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1vKV.jpg)

[Windows feature on and off toggling - no Hyper-V there!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iChr.jpg)

Comment: Only Windows 8.1 Professional supports Hyper-V.  It cannot be enabled on the edition of Windows 8.1 you have installed. Task Manager indicates virtualization is disabled.  Are you sure you don’t have Windows 8.1 Professional?

Comment: yep it look like it's a standard version of windows 8.1. Not sure what's happening.

Comment: Then that is the problem. If you're not running Windows 8.1 Professional you will not be able to activate HyperV, regardless whether your hardware supports it.

Comment: Please look on the serial number plate and get the model number; you are missing at least five digits for us to see if your hardware is Hyper-V compatible. Also, 4MB is the minimum spec; for practical use, 8MB would be much better, IF your CPU is Hyper-V capable.

Answer (score 0):

It will never work with your existing configuration.  As per [Microsoft Technet](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2014/03/10/step-by-step-enabling-hyper-v-for-use-on-windows-8-1/) The following prerequisites are required to successfully run Client Hyper-V on Windows 8.1:

Windows 8 Pro or Enterprise 64 bit Operating System (which you do not have), and a 64 bit processor with Second Level Address Translation (SLAT) which you can confirm by running [COREINFO.EXE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/coreinfo) as described [on MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uk_faculty_connection/2012/10/24/hyper-v-list-of-slat-capable-cpus-for-hosts/).

You could upgrade the OS, but until you confirm your PC hardware is compatible, it might be a waste of money.